# Calculation Of Days Difference Between BirthDay And Current Day

Tags: php, date

I have Database with column 'birthdate' which get filled by user in "Y-m-d" Format.

Now I want To echo Total Days Remained To Wish User Happy Birthday.

E.g. If Current Date is 2014-06-06 and Users Birthdate is 1980-06-26, So Birthday Is On Coming 26 June, Code Should Echo "Birthday Is After 20 Days"

What I have Tried Is As Follows -

```
$date1= date("m-d");
$date2=date("m-d",strtotime($data['birthdate']));

$dateDiff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$remainedDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));

echo "Birthday Is After $remainedDays Days";
```

But This Code Is Giving 0 Days

Comment: Use DateTime class which is far better.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?  If nothing, then please remove the tag.

Comment: Abhik, I posted a solution using the DateTime class below.

Comment: @OscarM. yes I saw the solution and its good, but missing few things i.e. handling leap year say if the DOB is `1980-02-29` then on a given year which is not leap year it will fail. I have added one algorithm to handle all these situation as an aswer, you may make a nice function out of this.

Comment: For non-leap years, the DateTime classes will assume your birday is on March 1st if you're born on leap day. If you need to handle it differently, then yes, you'd need to handle that yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least verbose way to do this is with the [DateTime classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and specifically with the [DateTime::diff method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). Note you should ensure the times are midnight for each date, then test if the birthday this year has already occurred.

```
<?php
$birthday = "1980-06-24";

// get date of birthday this calendar year
$parts = explode('-', $birthday, 2);
$birth_date = new DateTime(date('Y') . '-' . $parts[1] .' 00:00:00');
$today = new DateTime('midnight today');

if ($birth_date < $today) {
    // next birthday is in one year
    $birth_date->modify("+1 Year"); 
}

// get number of days days remaining
$diff = $birth_date->diff($today);

if ($diff->days > 0) {
    echo "There are " . $diff->days . " remaining until your birthday.";
} else {
    echo "Happy birthday!";
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help. Handling Dates & Times in php can be tricky, but the DateTime extension simplifies so many things. I hate seeing people still use strtotime() and older functions. If you work a lot with dates (and eventually you will), Derrick Rethan's book on [Guide to Date and Time Programming](http://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-date-and-time-programming/) is a good reference to have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm you can use for upcoming B'days. This will also consider the leap year with B'day as 02/29

You can modify the code as per the need to have as per your requirement. It will check upcoming B'day or B'day which already expired.

```
$bday  = new DateTime("1980-06-26");
$today  = new DateTime();
$b_y = $bday->format('Y');
$b_d = $bday->format('d');
$b_m = $bday->format('m');

if((bool)$bday->format('L') && $b_d == 29 && $b_m == 2){
  if((bool)$today->format('L')){
    $bday_obj = new DateTime(date('Y').'-'.$b_m.'-'.$b_d);
    $diff = $bday_obj->diff($today);
  }else{
    for($i=1;$i++;$i<=3){
      $today->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
      if((bool)$today->format('L')){
        $bday_obj = new DateTime(date('Y').'-'.$b_m.'-'.$b_d);
        $diff = $bday_obj->diff($today);
        break ;
      }
    }
  }
}else{
  $bday_obj = new DateTime(date('Y').'-'.$b_m.'-'.$b_d);
  $diff = $bday_obj->diff($today);
}

$now = new DateTime() ;
if($now > $bday_obj){
  echo 'Your birthday was over '.$diff->format('%a days').' before';
}else{
  echo 'Your birthday is after  '.$diff->format('%a days');
}
```